# I cant add text to textProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to store a large text(70k char) to datastore. what I did is working fine on localhost. But When I upload it to gae it doesnt store anything. it just shows "{}"

if I rename textProperty to StringProperty and change the text, it works. where did I do the mistake?

my db.model:

```
class Eyut(db.Model):
    texx=db.TextProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=False)
    glink=db.StringProperty()
```

first add:

```
eks=Eyut(parent=_gazKey('yaz','yaze'),key_name='yaze')
eks.put()
```

adding text to it:

```
y=Eyut.get_by_key_name('yaze',parent=db.Key.from_path('Bed','yaz','yaze',1))
y.texx="any text"
y.put()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't present quite enough code but with a little guessing here's my simplest attempt at reproducing what you report:

```
class Bed(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

def _gazKey(x, y):
    return db.Key.from_path('Bed', x, y, 1)

class Eyut(db.Model):
    texx=db.TextProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=False)
    glink=db.StringProperty()

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        eks=Eyut(parent=_gazKey('yaz','yaze'),key_name='yaze')
        eks.put()
        y=Eyut.get_by_key_name('yaze',parent=db.Key.from_path('Bed','yaz','yaze',1))
        y.texx="any text"
        y.put()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(y.texx + '\n')
```

This code does **not** show any problem and in particular not the one you report -- the entity and its text property are just as expected.

Please edit your question to show the minimal changes to this code that **will** reproduce the problem you report.

Comment: you were right. It was saving after all. I was checking at datastore only . when I saw that scopes I thought it wasnt saving. but it gives the text when if you call

Answer (score -2):

[StringProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#StringProperty)

> A short string. Takes a Python str or unicode (basestring) value of
>   500 characters or less.

[TextProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#TextProperty)

> A long string.
>
> Unlike StringProperty, a TextProperty value can be more than 500
>   characters long.

Comment: how might copying the definition from doc help to me?

Comment: it might inform you that you are trying to save more characters then is possible in that type of field. 70k characters is more then 500. I've voted to close in any case as as it was saving after all, as you note.